# I too saw a star like object moving across the sky it appeared to be a star moving!

Tags: identify-this-object

I too saw a star like object moving across the sky from Bournemouth towards say Parkstone, it appeared to be a star moving for quite a long time until it disappeared from my view!
I have seen this the last two nights and so have my family, it's not the Space Station as I see this regularly as my Star Walk app, you can add in when you know what the object is! But unless I know the name of this object I can't track it on my app, does anyone know what it could Be?
It is not a plane as far too high like a star moving but fast across the sky? This was timed 22:10 on Sunday August 28th 2017

Comment: There are hundreds of satellites that are visible to the naked eye depending on how dark the sky is. You might want to look into an app that shows all of the visible satellites so that you don't have to guess which one it is to add to your app.

Comment: The thing is the thing you saw could be anything from a satellite to a plane (since I am not really sure we can calculate height with our naked eye too easily). If you posted an image or more description of how it kinda looks like, that would help 'us' to determine if it is one and if one, its call sign.

Comment: @MichaelP.Jouanneau Planes have timed blinking lights of different colors.

Comment: Some are meteors. Even if they don't look like a shooting light they still can be meteors. They look like stars which appear a little bright first, but get dimmer and dimmer when they move through the sky, and finally disappear.

Answer (score 2):

This is very probably another artificial satellite, there are hundreds of them

references : 
http://www.pixalytics.com/sats-orbiting-earth-2016/
https://www.universetoday.com/42198/how-many-satellites-in-space/